# How can I stop an implicit TextBox style from getting inherited in a ComboBox when DisplayMemberPath is not set?

Tags: wpf, styles, implicit-style

I have two `ComboBoxes`. One is bound to a list of enum values, while the other is bound to a list of custom class objects and has the `DisplayMemberPath` property set.

The `ComboBox` bound to the enum values applies an implicit `TextBlock` style, while the `ComboBox` that uses the `DisplayMemberPath` property does not.

Using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) I can verify that both `ComboBoxes` are rendered with the exact same set of controls (a `<ContentPresenter>` containing a `<TextBlock>`), however the `TextBlock` in the `ComboBox` without the `DisplayMemberPath` set contains a `Margin` of 5 while the one with `DisplayMemberPath` set does not.

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>

<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding EnumCollection}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEnum}" />

<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

[image: Screenshot]

Why is this? And what can I do to stop the Enum `ComboBox` from inheriting the implicit `TextBlock` style?

Comment: My assumption would be that the `DisplayMemberPath` creates a `DataTemplate`, styles will not be applied within its scope.

Comment: @H.B. It does... per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) "This property is a simple way to define a default template that describes how to display the data objects". I know I can do some obnoxious ugly workaround with `<ComboBox.Resources>` but I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: @KDiTraglia That would make both `ComboBoxes` inherit the implicit `TextBlock` style, and I wanted the reverse: for both of them to *not* inherit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption would be that the `DisplayMemberPath` creates a `DataTemplate`, and styles will not be applied within its scope.

Try setting `DisplayMemberPath="."` to make the first `ComboBox` use a `DataTemplate` containing `<TextBlock Text="{Binding .}">`, which will prevent the implicit style from getting applied.

Comment: I knew you'd know the answer to this ^_^ That works fine, thank you

Comment: It is more like i guessed it :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with that :) I find a disturbingly large percentage of my programming is just educated guesses. Or as I call it, "educated trial-and-error".

Comment: @Rachel: Well, if you have a deep understanding of the system, the guesses become predictions. Here i just thought that `DisplayMemberPath` causes `{Binding <VALUE>}` so `{Binding .}` should work.